# My program for counting how many vowels in a user input sentence doesn't count the same vowel twice. How do i fix this?

Tags: python, count

```
print ("Sentence analysis")

Sentence = (input("Please enter a sentence"))


def WordCount(Sentence):
    words = (Sentence.count(' ')+1)
    print ("There are", words ,"words in this sentence")
WordCount(Sentence)
```

The code above is fine and used to count how many words in the input sentence.

```
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
count=0
for v in vowels:
    if v in Sentence:
        count+=1


print (count)
```

When running, say if I input `a a e i o u` would only count 5 vowels whereas there are 6. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Use `.count()`:

```
count = 0
for v in vowels:
    count += Sentence.count(v)
```

Or better:

```
count = sum(Sentence.count(v) for v in vowels)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are doing your check in reverse. You want to go over your sentence and check each letter against vowels:

```
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
count=0
for s in Sentence:
    if s in vowels:
        count+=1


print (count)
```

For a nicer approach, however, check out [@zondo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35627541/1832539) answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that when you loop through `v` in `vowels` and check if `v` is in `Sentence` it only checks if it `v` is present in `Sentance` not how many times. If you flip it around so it checks through `Sentence` first and check each letter to see if it is in `vowels` it will check all of the letters in `Sentence`.

```
print ("Sentence analysis")

Sentence = (input("Please enter a sentence"))

vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
count=0
for letter in Sentence:
    if letter in vowels:
        count+=1

print (count)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first code can be simplified the `WordCount()` function as:

```
print(len(Sentence.split()))
```

or:

```
import re
print(len(re.findall(r'\w+', Sentence)))
```